# Leaflet directive - display png full screen

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, geojson, angular-leaflet-directive

I am currently working on a project that has to display geojson data on a map.

I am using the `leaflet-directive` for AngularJS and it works fine.

My map is correctly displayed with the geojson data.

**ANGULAR CONTROLLER**

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    intersection: {
        lat: 50.891,
        lng: 4.258,
        zoom: 14
    },
    defaults: {
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    },
    geojson : {},
    layers: {
        baselayers: {
            xyz: {
                name: 'OpenStreetMap (XYZ)',
                url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                type: 'xyz'
            }
        },
        overlays: {}
    }
});

$scope.$watch("intersection.zoom", function(zoom) {
    if(zoom > 17){
        $scope.layers.overlays = {
            wms: {
                name: 'intersectionDraw',
                type: 'wms',
                visible: true,
                url: 'img/map.png'
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Now I would like to add a feature. I would like to display a png drawing when my zoom reaches the max zoom.For the moment, my code is displaying the png in mosaic. I want this png to get the full height and width of my map and see only this. There is no need to zoom more on this png but if I zoom out the "normal" map will be shown again

**The mosaic PNG**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`L.ImageOverlay`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#imageoverlay). See [Leaflet single picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037287/leaflet-single-picture/36037791#36037791) and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/debug/map/image-overlay.html

Comment: How can I use this with the angular-leaflet-directive ?

Comment: See the [example of using a `ImageOverlay` in the leaflet-angular documentation](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/layers/imageoverlay-example). Apparently you can create a layer of type `imageOverlay`, with options as per the non-angular `L.ImageOverlay`.

Comment: Thx I did it but the image is totally transform and does not fit the whole size

Comment: + My geoJSON does not appears over the image